# Multiple Segue Storyboard whit TableViewCell using Parse.com

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, uistoryboardsegue

in my app I need to run 2 "Storyboard Follows" in practice, when the user selects the cell is pushed into a specific view controller based on a boolean value.

The Tableview contains a list of exam  ... I wish that:

when the user selects the exam Not Completed is pushed into the ViewController 1
  when the user selects the exam Complete is pushed into the ViewController 2

Until now I always used

**- (Void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) sender follows: (id) sender**

but of course when I connect two follows from the cell, the app crashes

I show you the code
P.S. in the storyboard I connected the cell to two different viewcontroller .. If this is wrong you can tell me how to fix this?
Thanks for everything and sorry if the question is not really a problem :)

I'm used Parse.com

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {

 if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"DettaglioOggetto"])
 {
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     PFObject *rowObject = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     if([[rowObject objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_STATUS] boolValue])
     {
         //DATO CONVALIDATO
         PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         FFDettagliEsami *FFDestinationDetails = [segue destinationViewController];
         FFDestinationDetails.FFObjectForDetails = object;

     } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Dettaglio"]){

      //   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         FFSchedaEsameConvalidato *FFDestinationDetails = [segue destinationViewController];
         FFDestinationDetails.FFObjectForDetails1 = object;

     }

 }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved ... I connected follows directly from viewcontroller containing the TableView with CTRL + drag the view controller target, then

```
- (Void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) sender follows: (id) sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @ "SegueDaConvalidare"]) {
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
FFDettagliEsami * = FFDestinationDetails [more destinationViewController];
FFDestinationDetails.FFObjectForDetails = object;}
    
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @ "SegueConvalidato"]) {
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
FFSchedaEsameConvalidato * = FFDestinationDetails [more destinationViewController];
FFDestinationDetails.FFObjectForDetails1 = object;}
}
```

Then I implemented the method didSelectedRowAtIndexPath and now everything is working correctly.